# VSTO Outlook E-Mail Get Recipient.AutoResponse

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

I’ve built a custom address book [c sharp winform], accessible from an Outlook Ribbon [Outlook 2010]

When a user types an email, then adds some users to To, CC etc they can then click the Custom Address Book button to load a datagridview of all users within my organisation.

When they do this I loop all Recipients already added and add them to one of three list boxes in the WinForm.
Example: TO listbox, CC listbox and BCC listbox.

This is all working great!

What I would like to do now is give the user a button which can automatically remove every user who has an Automatic Reply on.

Is this possible using Recipient.AutoResponse?  I have some users who have an AutoReponse enabled but when I attempt to use Recipient.AutoReponse it simply comes back as a null, is .AutoResponse expecting their SMTP address?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to use EWS (or managed EWS API) to retrieve the user OOF status - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh532559(v%3Dexchg.80)